# How to get a regression summary in scikit-learn like R does?

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, linear-regression, summary

As an R user, I wanted to also get up to speed on scikit.

Creating a linear regression model(s) is fine, but can't seem to find a reasonable way to get a **standard summary of regression output.**

Code example:

```
# Linear Regression
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Load the diabetes datasets
dataset = datasets.load_diabetes()

# Fit a linear regression model to the data
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(dataset.data, dataset.target)
print(model)

# Make predictions
expected = dataset.target
predicted = model.predict(dataset.data)

# Summarize the fit of the model
mse = np.mean((predicted-expected)**2)
print model.intercept_, model.coef_, mse, 
print(model.score(dataset.data, dataset.target))
```

Issues:

- seems like the **intercept** and **coef** are built into the model, and I just type `print` (second to last line) to see them.
- What about **all the other standard regression output like R^2, adjusted R^2, p values, etc.** If I read the examples correctly, seems like you have to write a function/equation for each of these and then print it.
- So, is there no standard summary output for lin. reg. models?
- Also, in my printed array of outputs of coefficients, **there are no variable names associated with each of these? I just get the numeric array.** Is there a way to print these where I get an output of the coefficients and the variable they go with?

My printed output:

```
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False)
152.133484163 [ -10.01219782 -239.81908937  519.83978679  324.39042769 -792.18416163
  476.74583782  101.04457032  177.06417623  751.27932109   67.62538639] 2859.69039877
0.517749425413
```

Notes: Started off with Linear, Ridge and Lasso. I have gone through the examples. Below is for the basic OLS.

Comment: Many standard evaluation metrics are available in [`sklearn.metrics`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#sklearn-metrics-metrics).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There exists no R type regression summary report in sklearn. The main reason is that sklearn is used for predictive modelling / machine learning and the evaluation criteria are based on performance on previously unseen data (such as predictive r^2 for regression).

There does exist a summary function for classification called `sklearn.metrics.classification_report` which calculates several types of (predictive) scores on a classification model.

For a more classic statistical approach, take a look at `statsmodels`.

Comment: Kudos for the pointer to `statsmodels`. However, this main reason for the lack of a summary functionality is strange. Good model-building requires some amount of introspection of the model itself to at least answer the question "does this make sense?"

Answer (score 53):

I use:

```
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
def regression_results(y_true, y_pred):

    # Regression metrics
    explained_variance=metrics.explained_variance_score(y_true, y_pred)
    mean_absolute_error=metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred) 
    mse=metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred) 
    mean_squared_log_error=metrics.mean_squared_log_error(y_true, y_pred)
    median_absolute_error=metrics.median_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)
    r2=metrics.r2_score(y_true, y_pred)

    print('explained_variance: ', round(explained_variance,4))    
    print('mean_squared_log_error: ', round(mean_squared_log_error,4))
    print('r2: ', round(r2,4))
    print('MAE: ', round(mean_absolute_error,4))
    print('MSE: ', round(mse,4))
    print('RMSE: ', round(np.sqrt(mse),4))
```

Comment: Just FYI `median_absolute_error` is not printed. Otherwise, thanks for this nice function, I noticed the missing print when I used this code snippet.

Answer (score 30):

statsmodels package gives a quiet decent summary

```
from statsmodels.api import OLS
OLS(dataset.target,dataset.data).fit().summary()
```

Answer (score 11):

[image]You can do using statsmodels

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
X = sm.add_constant(X.ravel())
results = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
results.summary()
```

results.summary() will organize the results into three tabels

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following option to have a summary table:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

#log_clf = LogisticRegression()

log_clf =sm.Logit(y_train,X_train)

classifier = log_clf.fit()

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

print(classifier.summary2())
```

Answer (score -13):

Use `model.summary()` after predict

```
# Linear Regression
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# load the diabetes datasets
dataset = datasets.load_diabetes()

# fit a linear regression model to the data
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(dataset.data, dataset.target)
print(model)

# make predictions
expected = dataset.target
predicted = model.predict(dataset.data)

# >>>>>>>Print out the statistics<<<<<<<<<<<<<
model.summary()

# summarize the fit of the model
mse = np.mean((predicted-expected)**2)
print model.intercept_, model.coef_, mse, 
print(model.score(dataset.data, dataset.target))
```

Comment: In the current version of Sklearn 0.19.1 a linear regresion object doesn't have this summary method/attribute. It's not found on the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) and when I run it in my own environment I get the error `'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'summary'`