# Summary of regression in scikit_learn

Tags: multiple-regression, python, scikit-learn

If I perform a linear regression in R, I get a nice summary of the resulting model, $R^2$, p-values for different features, etc.

If I do the same in scikit_learn, I get nothing of this. Are there any ways to print summary of the model there?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319259/sci-kit-and-regression-summary/26326883#26326883

Comment: as a general comment: scikit-learn is for machine learning, not for performing classical statistics. It is predictive power of the model that counts, not statistical significance. Totally useless predictive models can be statistically significant.

Answer (score 6):

Scikit-learn does not, to my knowledge, have a summary function like R.  However, statmodels, another Python package, does.  Plus, it's implementation is much more similar to R.

```
from statsmodels.formula.api  import ols
#you need a Pandas dataframe df with columns labeled Y, X, & X2
est = ols(formula = 'Y ~  X + X2', data = df).fit()
est.summary()
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of existence of statsmodel. But may be there're some external packages which might provide similar interface to scikit learn?