# statistical summary table in sklearn.linear_model.ridge?

Tags: python, statsmodels, sklearn-pandas

In OLS form StatsModels, results.summary shows the summary of regression results (such as AIC, BIC, R-squared, ...)

Is there any way to have this summary table in sklearn.linear_model.ridge?

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me. Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As I know, there is no R(or Statsmodels)-like summary table in sklearn. (Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26326883/3054161))

Instead, if you need it, there is [statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit_regularized](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit_regularized.html#statsmodels-regression-linear-model-ols-fit-regularized) class. (`L1_wt=0` for ridge regression.)

For now, it seems that `model.fit_regularized(~).summary()` returns `None` despite of docstring below. But the object has `params`, `summary()` can be used somehow.

> Returns: A RegressionResults object, of the same type returned by `fit`.

**Example.**

Sample data is not for ridge regression, but I will try anyway.

In.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

statsmodels.__version__
```

Out.

```
'0.8.0rc1'
```

In.

```
data = sm.datasets.ccard.load()

print "endog: " + data.endog_name
print "exog: " + ', '.join(data.exog_name)

data.exog[:5, :]
```

Out.

```
endog: AVGEXP
exog: AGE, INCOME, INCOMESQ, OWNRENT
Out[2]:
array([[ 38.    ,   4.52  ,  20.4304,   1.    ],
       [ 33.    ,   2.42  ,   5.8564,   0.    ],
       [ 34.    ,   4.5   ,  20.25  ,   1.    ],
       [ 31.    ,   2.54  ,   6.4516,   0.    ],
       [ 32.    ,   9.79  ,  95.8441,   1.    ]])
```

In.

```
y, X = data.endog, data.exog

model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results_fu = model.fit()

print results_fu.summary()
```

Out.

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.543
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.516
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     20.22
Date:                Wed, 19 Oct 2016   Prob (F-statistic):           5.24e-11
Time:                        17:22:48   Log-Likelihood:                -507.24
No. Observations:                  72   AIC:                             1022.
Df Residuals:                      68   BIC:                             1032.
Df Model:                           4                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x1            -6.8112      4.551     -1.497      0.139     -15.892       2.270
x2           175.8245     63.743      2.758      0.007      48.628     303.021
x3            -9.7235      6.030     -1.613      0.111     -21.756       2.309
x4            54.7496     80.044      0.684      0.496    -104.977     214.476
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       76.325   Durbin-Watson:                   1.692
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):              649.447
Skew:                           3.194   Prob(JB):                    9.42e-142
Kurtosis:                      16.255   Cond. No.                         87.5
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

In.

```
frames = []
for n in np.arange(0, 0.25, 0.05).tolist():
    results_fr = model.fit_regularized(L1_wt=0, alpha=n, start_params=results_fu.params)

    results_fr_fit = sm.regression.linear_model.OLSResults(model, 
                                                           results_fr.params, 
                                                           model.normalized_cov_params)
    frames.append(np.append(results_fr.params, results_fr_fit.ssr))

    df = pd.DataFrame(frames, columns=data.exog_name + ['ssr*'])
df.index=np.arange(0, 0.25, 0.05).tolist()
df.index.name = 'alpha*'
df.T
```

Out.

[image]

In.

```
%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(14, 4))

ax[0] = df.iloc[:, :-1].plot(ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set_title('Coefficient')

ax[1] = df.iloc[:, -1].plot(ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set_title('SSR')
```

Out.

[image]

In.

```
results_fr = model.fit_regularized(L1_wt=0, alpha=0.04, start_params=results_fu.params)
final = sm.regression.linear_model.OLSResults(model, 
                                              results_fr.params, 
                                              model.normalized_cov_params)

print final.summary()
```

Out.

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.543
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.516
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     20.17
Date:                Wed, 19 Oct 2016   Prob (F-statistic):           5.46e-11
Time:                        17:22:49   Log-Likelihood:                -507.28
No. Observations:                  72   AIC:                             1023.
Df Residuals:                      68   BIC:                             1032.
Df Model:                           4                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x1            -5.6375      4.554     -1.238      0.220     -14.724       3.449
x2           159.1412     63.781      2.495      0.015      31.867     286.415
x3            -8.1360      6.034     -1.348      0.182     -20.176       3.904
x4            44.2597     80.093      0.553      0.582    -115.564     204.083
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       76.819   Durbin-Watson:                   1.694
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):              658.948
Skew:                           3.220   Prob(JB):                    8.15e-144
Kurtosis:                      16.348   Cond. No.                         87.5
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I am not familiar with R. In python, I had imported ols from statsmodels.formula.api. I applied this command, model=ols.ols("y~a1+a2+a3+a4",data).fit(). Then model.summary() will show me the summary statistical table. I would like to apply ridge regression on my data. I tried model=ols.ols("y~a1+a2+a3+a4",data).fit_regularized(L1_wt=0,alpha=0.005), but the results are the same as without regularization. I do appreciate that if you guide me to solve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @zhr And just so you know, `.fit_regularized(~).summary()` seems not implemented yet unlike logit's one. So I tried some trick with `OLSResult` class call above.

Comment: @su79eu7k - Assuming `ssr` refers to Sum of squared residuals, isn't the scale of `ssr` too broad to be useful of interpretation for comparing different alpha values wrt regularized fit  ?

Comment: @ekta And some of them are categorical data(!) so I've mentioned: "Sample data is not for ridge regression, but I will try anyway." ;) You can check more detail about the dataset at http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~wgreene/Text/econometricanalysis.htm, Data Sets > Table F9.1

Comment: I think there is an issue with this solution. It is combining the reporting from the regularized and non-regularized trained models in some unholy matrimony. As evidence, try running the above script without training the non-regularized model - it won't work. This is because the normalized cov params have not been set up for regularized models yet (I think!)

Comment: As a work around I am going to use the reporting from the non-regularized model to help me interpret the results of the regularized one. Not ideal, but it will do for now. The issue with combining them is that the std err for each coefficient is not impacted by the regularization, so a variable that is significant, but has been shrunk due to the regularization, may look insignificant. Does that make sense?

Comment: what will be the equivalent of `sm.regression.linear_model.OLSResults` for glm model in poisson regression?

Comment: I am trying to use final = sm.regression.linear_model.OLSResults(model, 
                                              results_fr.params, 
                                              model.normalized_cov_params), but I am getting the following error: AttributeError: 'OLS' object has no attribute 'normalized_cov_params'. Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Bugee, I created the following function that returns the statsmodels metrics such as rsquared and rsquared_adj, and summary().

You can use sklearn linear models (LinearRegression, Lasso, Ridge...) and statsmodels OLS and regularized OLS too.

```
from statsmodels.tools.tools import pinv_extended
import statsmodels.api as sm
import sklearn, statsmodels

def regression_analysis(X, y, model):
    
    is_statsmodels = False
    is_sklearn = False
    
    # check for accepted linear models
    if type(model) in [sklearn.linear_model._base.LinearRegression,
                       sklearn.linear_model._ridge.Ridge,
                       sklearn.linear_model._ridge.RidgeCV,
                       sklearn.linear_model._coordinate_descent.Lasso,
                       sklearn.linear_model._coordinate_descent.LassoCV,
                       sklearn.linear_model._coordinate_descent.ElasticNet,
                       sklearn.linear_model._coordinate_descent.ElasticNetCV,
                      ]:
        is_sklearn = True
    elif type(model) in [statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS, 
                         statsmodels.base.elastic_net.RegularizedResults,
                        ]:
        is_statsmodels = True
    else:
        print("Only linear models are supported!")
        return None
    
    
    
    has_intercept = False
    
    if is_statsmodels and all(np.array(X)[:,0]==1):
        # statsmodels add_constant has been used already
        has_intercept = True  
    elif is_sklearn and model.intercept_:
        has_intercept = True
        

    
    if is_statsmodels:
        # add_constant has been used already
        x = X
        model_params = model.params
    else: # sklearn model
        if has_intercept:
            x = sm.add_constant(X)
            model_params = np.hstack([np.array([model.intercept_]), model.coef_])
        else:
            x = X
            model_params = model.coef_
        
    #y = np.array(y).ravel()
    
    # define the OLS model
    olsModel = sm.OLS(y, x)
    
    pinv_wexog,_ = pinv_extended(x)
    normalized_cov_params = np.dot(pinv_wexog, np.transpose(pinv_wexog))
    
    
    return sm.regression.linear_model.OLSResults(olsModel, model_params, normalized_cov_params)
```

**How to use it?**

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge


skridge = Ridge(alpha=0.2, max_iter=9000, tol=1e-5, fit_intercept=True)
skridge.fit(X,y)

result = regression_analysis(X, y, skridge)
result.summary()
```

Comment: this is a nice elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
from statsmodels.tools.tools import pinv_extended
X_train = sm.add_constant(X_train)
model = sm.OLS(y_train, X_train)

# If True, the model is refit using only the variables that have non-zero 
# coefficients in the regularized fit. The refitted model is not regularized.
result = model.fit_regularized(
                    method = 'elastic_net',
                    alpha = alp,
                    L1_wt = l1,
                    start_params = None,
                    profile_scale = False,
                    #refit = True,
                    refit = False,
                    maxiter = 9000,
                    zero_tol = 1e-5,
                    )

pinv_wexog,_ = pinv_extended(model.wexog)
normalized_cov_params = np.dot(pinv_wexog, np.transpose(pinv_wexog))


final = sm.regression.linear_model.OLSResults(model, 
                                  result.params, 
                                  normalized_cov_params)
#print(final.summary())
x = sm.add_constant(X_test)
#x = X_test
R2 = r2_score(y_test, final.predict(x))

p = final.pvalues
t = final.tvalues
```

Comment: What does it do? You should explain your solution

Comment: Worked perfectly to get model summary()

Comment: what is alp in the parameters?