# How to Output Regression Table in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regression

How do I add a Regression table ( table that includes t-statistic, p-value, r^2 etc.). I've attached an image of some of my code.

[image: Regression code]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a regression summary in Python scikit like R does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319259/how-to-get-a-regression-summary-in-python-scikit-like-r-does)

Answer (score 0):

`sklearn` is aimed at predictive modeling, so you don’t get the regression table that you are used to. An alternative in Python to sklearn is `statsmodels`.

See also [How to get a regression summary in Python scikit like R does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319259/how-to-get-a-regression-summary-in-python-scikit-like-r-does)

Answer (score 0):

I have read about two ways statsmodel and classification_report

STATS MODEL

`import statsmodels.api as sm`

`X = sm.add_constant(X.ravel())`

`results = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()`

`results.summary()`

CLASSIFICATION REPORT

`from sklearn.metrics import classifiation_report`

`y_preds = reg.predict(X_test)`

`print(classification_report(y_test,y_preds)`